# failed to build apk with ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Tags: ionic3

My app take long time so show main page after splash screen so I use this

```
ionic cordova  build android --prod --release
```

But I got error :

```
[20:28:35]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[20:28:35]  Error: ./src/app/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './a
pp.module.ngfactory' in
            'D:\losts\src\app' resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\losts\src
\app' using description file:
            D:\losts\package.json (relative path: ./src/app) Field 'browser' doe
sn't contain a valid alias configuration
            after using description file: D:\losts\package.json (relative path:
./src/app) using description file:
            D:\losts\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory
) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't
            contain a valid alias configuration D:\losts\src\app\app.module.ngfa
ctory doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser'
            doesn't contain a valid alias configuration D:\losts\src\app\app.mod
ule.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist .js Field
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration D:\losts\src\a
pp\app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
            .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration D:
\losts\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.json
            doesn't exist as directory
```

where is the problem or what i can do to make it faster

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1309) doesn't help you?

Comment: try to update @ionic/app-scripts if it works

Comment: I use android studio to create  release builds .

Comment: i update ionic/app-scripts and its work now, but when run the app its not stable and most of plugins not loaded like, native storage and when i write in input text its type with stranger charters